# Как получить комментарий платежа webmoney и сумму переведенных денег?

Tags: php, xml

Всем привет! Такое дело: нужно для последующего всовования в таблицу мускула получить сумму платежа webmoney и комментарий к нему. А как это сделать? В их API подобного не нашел.

Comment: Через какой номер интерфейса идет работа?

Comment: @ArchieO'Hare никакой. Я пока не работал с их API и интерфейсами а просто спрашиваю как.

Comment: В ответах на запросы по интерфейсам X3 и X4 есть параметры `operation\amount` и `operation\desc`. Если я правильно понял вопрос - то это то, что нужно.

Comment: @ArchieO'Hare спасибо. А не подскажешь случайно как например сделать если я не знаю WMID человека, который мне переслал деньги?